# If Button1 was clicked at any point in time prior to Button2 being clicked, prompt message

Tags: vb.net

I need to prompt a message if a user clicked button1 and then clicked button2 at some point later on.

Code will look something like:

```
Private Sub button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button2.Click

   if button1.clicked then 

      messagebox.show("Are you sure you want to click button2 after clicking button1?" , "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)

         if messagebox.userselected.ok then   

             Me.Dispose()
             Me.Close()

         else
             'do nothing
         end if

   end if

End Sub
```

Comment: Use a Boolean flag that you set to True when button one has been clicked. Then check the Boolean flag for being true when button two is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim Flag as Boolean = False

Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click  
   Flag = True       
End Sub

Private Sub button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button2.Click   
  If Flag Then
    If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to click button2 after clicking button1?" , "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) = DialogResult.Ok Then
      Me.Close()
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```